# Blackberry Browserfield example app not launching

Tags: blackberry, browserfield

I'm attempting to run a very simple Blackberry/Java application which implements the BrowserField class.  When I launch it in the simulator it just hangs.  When I launch it on my device nothing happens.

JRE: 7.0
Simulator:  4.0.0.141

```
  package mypackage;

  import net.rim.device.api.browser.field2.BrowserField;
  import net.rim.device.api.browser.field2.BrowserFieldConfig;
  import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
  import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

 public class BrowserJazz extends UiApplication
 {
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    BrowserJazz app = new BrowserJazz();
    app.enterEventDispatcher();
 }

 public void BrowserJazz()
 {
    pushScreen(new BrowserFieldDemoScreen());
 }
 }

 class BrowserFieldDemoScreen extends MainScreen
 {
public BrowserFieldDemoScreen()
{
    BrowserFieldConfig myBrowserFieldConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig();




    myBrowserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,
           BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);

    BrowserField browserField = new BrowserField(myBrowserFieldConfig);

    /*BrowserFieldListener listener = new BrowserFieldListener() {
        public void documentLoaded(BrowserField browserField) throws Exception
        {
            // the document has loaded, do something ...
            Dialog.inform("PAGE LOADED!");
        }
    };*/

    add(browserField);
    //browserField.addListener( listener );

    browserField.requestContent("http://www.google.com");
    //browserField.addListener( listener );

  }
  }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using "NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER" which only support OS 5 and above as you can read from browserfield doc http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserFieldConfig.html#NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER 
and as you said you using an old simulator "Simulator: 4.0.0.141"